# Android Theme Issue using AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-dialog

I don't see the line in Edittext when using TextInputLayout on Android 4.4 version tabs.

Everything is perfect on Nexus 5 which is running 6.0.

Please take a look at the screenshot:

**Samsung TAB running 4.4**

[image]

**Nexus 5 running 6.0**

[image]

Above is an XML and opening it throught a dialog. I am opening the above in dialog box something like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog));
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
```

Comment: share your xml code.

Comment: TextInputLayout is a part ofmaterial device which is suppoted by lollipop and above devices.

Comment: @DAgrawal: Don't think so... I can see it working properly on screen without a dialog

Comment: Can somebody help me with this? I am struggling with this?

Comment: This may have been a bug with TextInput in the support library. I cannot reproduce this issue in Android 4.4 anymore. But you haven't posted the XML code, thats where the issue must lie or can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog 

AlertDialog.Builder builder =
       new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
            builder.setTitle("TITLE");
            builder.setMessage("YOUR MESSAGE....");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);
            builder.show();
```

**style.xml :**

```
    <style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle"   parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">#FFCC00</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:background">#666666</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: No luck still the same. :(