# Appearance issue in spinners in Android studio

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, android-theme, appearance

I put two spinners in the same activity, one for City and the other for Town. When the user chooses a City, the Town spinner should populate with items according to the City that was chosen.

My problem is, the color of the background and the text is always different from the first one, however they have the same style and attributes. I couldn't find any logical solution and I didn't find any suggestion in web.

Do you have any idea about the reason or the solution?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:onClick="pickDate"
            android:text="Select date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Distribution date"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="The governorate"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/static_spinner"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="The district"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/district_spinner"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Place ID" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/plcID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:onClick="next"
            android:text="Next" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainInfoActivity file**

```
public class MainInfoActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textView, plcID;
    Spinner staticSpinner;
    Spinner dynamicSpinner;
    Spinner districtSpinner;
    CharSequence[] arrayDistrict;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> districtAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_info_activity);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewDate);
        plcID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plcID);

        //Drop down lists

        staticSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.static_spinner);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
        final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.governorate_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        staticAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        staticSpinner.setAdapter(staticAdapter);

        districtSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.district_spinner) ;

        districtAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                R.array.Anbar, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        districtAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        staticSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view1, int i, long l) {

                districtAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.array.Anbar, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

                districtAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                districtSpinner.setAdapter(districtAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post part of your code, and the xml files?

Comment: I posted the xml, the java code is very long I don't know which part I should post exactly

Comment: can you post the part of your java code where you set the Spinner list adapter?

Comment: @Ruan_Lopes scroll down the code above please, the part of the setting the adapter is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your code and it works fine for me.

The only difference I can find meaningful are in the lines below:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.governorate_array,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

and

```
districtAdapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.array.Anbar,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

instead of using **getApplicationContext()** can you try to use **this** as you did in the staticAdapter?

I once faced something similar where my application had a theme different from my activity and the widgets looked slightly different as well.

---

**UPDATE**

I would like to add some more info about the reason why I suggested the change above.

> Using the right Context is linked to another one of those behaviors.  While the framework will not complain and will return a perfectly good view hierarchy from a LayoutInflater created with the application context, the themes and styles from your app will not be considered in the process.  This is because Activity is the only Context on which the themes defined in your manifest are actually attached.  Any other instance will use the system default theme to inflate your views, leading to a display output you probably didn’t expect.

**Quote from this link**: https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

> By default, drop-down views are inflated against the theme of the
>        {@link Context} passed to the adapter's constructor. More.......

**ArrayAdapter source code:** https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#461

Comment: I can't use **this** because I use the code within a method depends to the block **staticSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener**

Comment: Replace **getApplicationContext()** to **MainInfoActivity.this** I think in your case it should work.

Comment: I replace it with what ? **this** doesn't work there

Comment: Use MainInfoActivity.this instead of getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

I was going to ask for more code, but then I found this similar solution in another question that can be useful for you: 
[Spinner Theme is Dark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31499657/spinner-theme-is-dark-in-android)

which basically consist on create your own theme for the upper spinner and bottom spinner. Check if this is close or related to your question. If don`t upload the activity where the spinners are added, for recreate the situation.

Comment: I looked at the link, I doesn't work with me. I posted the part of code dealing with the spinner